# How to resolve ValueError: x and y must be the same size

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I run this code block:

```
plt.plot(tag_counts[0:100], c='b')
plt.scatter(x=list(range(0,100,5)), y=tag_counts[0:100:5], c='orange', label="quantiles with 0.05 intervals")
# quantiles with 0.25 difference
plt.scatter(x=list(range(0,100,25)), y=tag_counts[0:100:25], c='m', label = "quantiles with 0.25 intervals")
for x,y in zip(list(range(0,100,25)), tag_counts[0:100:25]):
    plt.annotate(s="({} , {})".format(x,y), xy=(x,y), xytext=(x-0.05, y+500))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
print(len(tag_counts[0:100:5]), tag_counts[0:100:5])
```

I get this error:

```
1420 @functools.wraps(func)
   1421 def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
...
   4522 if s is None:
   4523     s = (20 if mpl.rcParams['_internal.classic_mode'] else
   4524          mpl.rcParams['lines.markersize'] ** 2.0)

ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

[image: And this chart]

I know I need to tweak the size of x and y, but I don't know how to display this in the code and what kind of change I should make. Can you help me please?
Also if you need more details you can check my codes here:https://www.kaggle.com/code/ajaysh/stackoverflow-tag-prediction/notebook

Comment: is this the full code? so that we can reproduce

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed the error I got:

```
num_quantiles = len(tag_counts[0:100:5])
x = list(range(0, num_quantiles * 5, 5))
y = tag_counts[0:100:5]
plt.plot(tag_counts[0:100], c='b')
plt.scatter(x=x, y=y, c='orange', label="quantiles with 0.05 intervals")
# quantiles with 0.25 difference
plt.scatter(x=x, y=y, c='m', label="quantiles with 0.25 intervals")

for x,y in zip(list(range(0,100,25)), tag_counts[0:100:25]):
    plt.annotate(s="({} , {})".format(x,y), xy=(x,y), xytext=(x-0.05, y+500))
```